# Match first character in string of same characters

Tags: regex

I would like to match the first character in a string of multiple same characters e.g. in a string like "hey (yes it's me (I know))", I would like to match the first bracket immediately after the word "know" such that I can capture the group "(I know)" only. What is the regex expression for such?

Example: I have a string with multiple "a"s in it, maybe an exclamation like "Whaaaaaat!". I want to only match the first "a" in that long string of "a"s.

Comment: I don't understand, can you clarify?

Comment: @Thefourthbird that will also match multiple ')'s after the last one.

Comment: You may capture it with `(.)\1*`. Note you may also capture the quantified back reference. Then, you may do whatever you want with the captures.

Answer (score 0):

You could match not a closing parenthesis using a negated character class, then capture a closing parenthesis and then use a positive lookahead to assert that there are one or more closing parenthesis following:

[`(?:[^)]|^)(\))(?=\1+)`](https://regex101.com/r/LhlrUf/1)

That would match:

- `(?:[^)]|^)` Match not an ) or the beginning of the string
- `(\))` Capture ) in a group
- `(?=\1+)` Positive lookahead that asserts that what follows is group 1 repeated one or more times

Or to match the first a:

[`(?:[^a]|^)(a)(?=\1+)`](https://regex101.com/r/UQb6M2/1)

Comment: OP wants to match any chars.

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: @Thefourthbird javascript, though language does not matter here

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
?\){1}
```

I was able to capture up to the first bracket, or whichever character was present, then I can modify to capture any number of those afterwards by changing the quantifier.